# Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are injective, then $ g \circ f$ is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Before looking at the book's proof, I tried doing the proof myself. After comparing the two I found mine to be a different than the book's. Please check to see if my reasoning is correct.

We have
$f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$. Since $f$ is injective, we can say that $f(x)$ is different for all distinct $x∈A$. Let the set S be the set of all elements in B that can be represented as $f(x)$ . We know that all distinct $y∈B$ have distinct $g(y) ∈ C$ thus all distinct $z∈S$ have a distinct $g(z)∈C$. Thus we can say that for all distinct $x∈A$ have a distinct $g(f(x))$

Please verify if my reasoning is correct and the proof is rigorous enough.

Comment: Is $S=\{f(x)\}$ or $f(A)$?

Comment: S is the set of elements of B that can be written as f(x).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. It is more common to say that $f(x)=f(x')\implies x=x'$ iff $f$ is injective, but you can also choose for $x\neq x'\implies f(x)\neq f(x')$. You reworded that in "$f(x)$ is different for all distinct $x\in A$". In my view that is rigorous as well.

Comment: Same question on the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477453/proof-of-properties-of-injective-and-surjective-functions).